# .git-completion.bash producing error on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: terminal, bash, git

I've followed the process for `git-completion` as per the description provided at https://medium.com/@farooqyousuf/autocomplete-git-commands-and-branch-names-in-terminal-on-mac-os-x-4e0beac0388a:

The first step is to execute this command in your terminal window, this is basically grabbing the ‘git-completion.bash’ script and putting it in your home directory.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Now add this line to your ‘~/.bash_profile’. This will allow the execution of the git autocomplete script if it present

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

You can now restart all your terminal windows or just refresh the terminal window you wish to use this script in. To refresh do:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Following is the error I'm getting while hitting `tab` key after typing `git`:

```
unknown option: --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
  [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
  [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
  [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
  <command> [<args>]
```

Comment: Whaty version of git are yiuy using and what version does bash_completion ask for?

Comment: `git version 2.17.1`

Comment: I'm getting the same on Mac and Ubuntu too. git versions 2.4.7 and 2.17.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem. After some digging, I finally figured out what the root problem is.

They made some major changes to the `git-completion.bash` script which requires a new feature in git v2.18, `--list-cmds`. The problem is that none of the package managers have updated to git v2.18 yet.

Most of the instructions out there say to download raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/`master`/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash . But that is not necessarily the best option because sometimes you will be downloading a newer `git-completion.bash` than your version of git supports.

So the solution is to download the `git-completion.bash` version that matches your git version. Then source it again. In this case:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v2.17.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Notice that it is referencing `v2.17.1` instead of `master`. Later, when you install git v2.18, then you can switch back to `master`, or `v2.18` tag.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! I was looking for the similar solution, as I remember the `git-completion.bash` was working earlier.

Comment: Fan-bloody-tastic

Comment: This resolves the issue of version tracking - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898614/1874627

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading the git to the latest version is the simplest solution. https://git-scm.com/download/mac

After that make sure you follow the steps

1. `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash`
2. Add this small command into the `.bash_profile` file 
   `if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
   . ~/.git-completion.bash
   fi`

Answer (score 2):

Don't build it from source; instead install from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

To install git with auto-completion, issue the following command:

```
 $ sudo port install git +bash_completion
```

close and reopen your Terminal and git completion should work

Comment: I've tried this but didn't resolve the issue. It's still the same.

Comment: Issue this command:  `sudo find / -type -name "git-completion.bash"` and post the results to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify your git version and make sure it is updated to at least 1.8.

I had an older version 1.7.11 but that didn't work and got the same error you have.

Comment: `git version 2.17.1`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Homebrew, you may want to

1. upgrade git:

   `brew upgrade git`
2. source the installed git-completion.bash in your `~/.bash_profile`:

   `. /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash`

This makes sure the installed git and completion script versions match.